# shake event to show required fields form fields?

Tags: jquery, html, css, validation

ok so i have this form and im validating it with onclick event and submit by on change

```
<form action="reservation.php" method="post">
                             <input class="date" id="from" name="from" type="text" value="<?php echo $from; ?>" onclick="document.getElementById('to').removeAttribute('disabled')" >   
                             <h5>Checkout</h5>
                             <input class="date" id="to" name="to" type="text" value="<?php echo $to; ?>" disabled onclick="document.getElementById('room_type').removeAttribute('disabled')">
                             <h5>Room</h5>
                             <select id="room_type" name="room_type" class="frm-field required" onChange='this.form.submit()' disabled>
                               <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select</option>
                                    <option value="Delux">Deluxe Rooms</option>       
                                    <option value="Executive">Executive Rooms</option>
                                    <option value="Suite">Suites</option>
                              </select>
                              <noscript><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Check"/></noscript>
                              </form>
```

say someone tries to straight away click on the Room select field then the Checkin and Checkout fields shake with a red border and if someone already selects value to the Checkin field but does not try to click on Checkout and again tried to go to select field then only the Checkout field shakes with red border letting the use know that is a required field?

hope someone can help out in achieving  this will appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$( document ).click(function() {
  $( "#toggle" ).effect( "shake" );
});
```

```css
#toggle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>shake demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Click anywhere to shake the box.</p>
<div id="toggle"></div>
 

</body>
</html>
```

On click event by using jqueryui , you can use [shake effect](http://api.jqueryui.com/shake-effect/)

$( "#to" ).effect( "shake" ).css( "border", "2px solid red" );

EDIT

Another solution using [animation css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) :-

```
<button id="shakebtn">shake</button>
<input class="date" id="to" name="to" type="text" value="<?php echo $to; ?>" disabled onclick="document.getElementById('room_type').removeAttribute('disabled')">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#shakebtn').click(function(){
       $('#to').removeClass().addClass('animated shake borderred').one('webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd', function(){
            $(this).removeClass();
       });
    });
</script>
```

css would be

```
.borderred {
    border:2px solid red
}
```

> EDIT as per your comment i have added a demo from [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/shake-effect/) please go
>   through for very basic configuration with js to fit in your code.

Comment: @Seeker Please try above code and demo to explain things from very basic demo. thanks! :)

Comment: mate im still unable to figure it how to make it work with my form above sob sob

Comment: You need to add the js under the script tag ! Use <script type="text/javascript"> or simply <script>

Comment: did that but still nothing is happening to my form

<code> <style>
    .borderred {
    border:2px solid red
}
</style>
    <script>
    $('#shakebtn').click(function(){
   $('#to').removeClass().addClass('animated shake borderred').one('webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd', function(){
        $(this).removeClass();
   });
});
</script></code>

Comment: For css solution you need to include animation.css here! https://raw.githubusercontent.com/daneden/animate.css/master/animate.css

Comment: also my form submit is onChange event without button mate

Comment: Have you include animation.css over fiddle ? another working demo http://jsfiddle.net/f9wRU/3/ though you do not have submit button you may code on change event! Simple ?

Comment: yes its animating but only if i click the shake button not on clickin on top of the disabled fields mate

Comment: You have to code it accordingly bro! I've shown may different way even added many examples ! with deep details!

Comment: yes bro figuring it out, 

could you tell me how do i make this code remove disbled only if there is value to thie to field? maybe on keyup event?

onclick="document.getElementById('to').removeAttribute('disabled')"

Comment: Not getting what excatly you want to do? as per my understanding  you should remove disabled onclick="document.getElementById('room_type').removeAttribute('disabled')

Comment: if ($(yourtextboxID.val() == '') {
        $('#yourtextboxID').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('#yourtextboxID').attr('disabled', '');
    }
Ok ?

Comment: ok as of now im removing the disable field when user click on the first field
and then second field enables but if no value in second field i do not wish to remove the disabled on the third field

onclick="document.getElementById('room_type').removeAttribute('disabled')" disabled="disabled"

Answer (score 0):

You want to set up some client-side validation for the fields, and when it fails, trigger the events that you wish to happen, which would be.

```
$('#button').click(function() {
  $( "#input" ).effect( "shake" ).css( "border", "2px solid red" );
});
```

Comment: how would i fit it to my form? im not too familiar with js, could you help out